# Correct Mouseposition on element while using CSS aspect ratio

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, mouse, aspect-ratio

I have a canvas that scales to the `16:9` aspect ratio. However the mouse does not take the offset (black background) into account.

The dotted green line marks the canvas. At the edge the mouse should display: `Mouse : 0% | 23%` rather than `Mouse : 7% | 23%`.

[image]

The problem seems to occur here:

```
var x = Math.floor( mouse.x / canvas.width * 100 ); 
var y = Math.floor( mouse.y / canvas.height * 100 );
```

It works fine when I go into fullscreen mode. *(because there is no offset)* But otherwise it does not take the offset into account.

---

**Additional Code:**

**CSS:**

```
#aspectoverlay {
    /*   16:9    */
    width: 100vw; 
    height: 56.25vw; /* 100/56.25 = 1.778 */
    border: 1px #AFFF00 dashed;
    max-height: 100vh;
    max-width: 177.78vh; /* 16/9 = 1.778 */
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;bottom:0; /* vertical center */
    left:0;right:0; /* horizontal center */
    z-index: 100;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

**JS:**

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('aspectoverlay');
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);
function resizeCanvas () {
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
}
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){
    mouse.x = e.x; 
    mouse.y = e.y;
});
var x = Math.floor( mouse.x / canvas.width * 100 ); 
var y = Math.floor( mouse.y / canvas.height * 100 );
ctx.fillText("Mouse : " + x + "% | " + y + "%", 50,50);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to take the offsets of the element into account like so

```
mouse.x = e.x - this.offsetLeft;
mouse.y = e.y - this.offsetTop;
```

And since you are using CSS to resize and setting the canvas to the innerHeight and Width, you can't use the canvas `width` and `height` for calculations anymore you need to use `offsetWidth` and `offsetHeight`

```
var x = Math.floor(mouse.x / canvas.offsetWidth * 100);
var y = Math.floor(mouse.y / canvas.offsetHeight * 100);
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/gm8kT/)**

**[Full Screen](http://fiddle.jshell.net/loktar/gm8kT/show/light/)**

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('aspectoverlay');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    mouse = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    };

ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);

function resizeCanvas() {
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
}

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    mouse.x = e.x - this.offsetLeft;
    mouse.y = e.y - this.offsetTop;

    var x = Math.floor(mouse.x / canvas.offsetWidth * 100);
    var y = Math.floor(mouse.y / canvas.offsetHeight * 100);
    ctx.fillText("Mouse : " + x + "% | " + y + "%", 50, 50);
});
```